# Firebase doesn't call back when using '.childAdded'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have the following code, written in Swift which I expect to be called each time a new record has been added to the my Database:

```
var databaseRef = Firebase()
    databaseRef = Firebase.init(url: "<MY_PROJECT_URL>")
    databaseRef.child(byAppendingPath: "channels").queryLimited(toFirst: 100).observe(.childAdded , with: { (snapshot) in
          print("New Message input by user")
    })
```

And this is my data structure:

[image]

So I basically create a listener for the branch 'channels'. The completion handler gets called only at the start of my program, then, never again. The strange thing is that if I use '.value' rather than '.childAdded' *it does work!* I am not interested in using '.value' since that returns me the whole chunk of data inside the 'channels' branch and I am really interested only in the single record that was added.  (actually one of those L1... guys. A new one of course) Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to find when a new user is added, or a new message is added?

Comment: A new message is added, a record such as the one named 'L1EEoVdYMEe...'

Comment: OK, so that's your problem.  The `child` of your query is actually the `messages` object, so it will not get called if an individual message is added to `messages`.

Comment: I think this is a problem as I don't think there's a way to query the first 100 users (as you are currently doing) and then get notified when ANY of them has a new message.  Are you trying to get new messages only for 1 user?  Or do you really need to get notified when any of the first 100 users has a new message?

Comment: Shoot, I see. You are right, it works exactly as you say. What can I do to achieve what I want then? I want to get alerted from any new message inside any user basically and process it.

Comment: If you are observing messages from all users at the same time I'd recommend restructuring your Firebase data a bit.  Make `messages` a top-level object, and then you can just observe that whole section.  I don't know what your messages look like, but I assume if you do this you will need to add a reference to the user inside the message so that you can get the new message added and still see which user wrote it.

Comment: @creeperspeak you nailed it. If you want to post your last message as a responde I can mark it as solved. Thanks pal

Comment: ciao @IgnacioOroná - Surely the problem is just the 100 limit?  Remove it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are observing messages from all users at the same time I'd recommend restructuring your Firebase data a bit. Make messages a top-level object, and then you can just observe that whole section. I don't know what your messages look like, but I assume if you do this you will need to add a reference to the user inside the message so that you can get the new message added and still see which user wrote it.